Data corruption and Memory Access Violation when trying to run TallyPrime on Linux with multiple users sharing data
I am trying to run TallyPrime on Linux with Wine and it works very well for a single user.
My client has a setup with Citrix on Windows Server where multiple users use app streaming and run multiple Tally prime instances running on the same Windows Server with data on an NTFS volume. I am trying to replicate this setup in Linux with Wine to save cost. I am using docker containers run Wine and use VNC to stream the X11 session to the browser and the setup works pretty well.
The problem comes when multiple containers access Tally data folder  in a Windows Citrix setup, but it fails in Linux. It produces errors related to database transactions when multiple clients access the data. Memory Access Violation, Data Corruption was common among them suggesting that being overwritten when multiple clients try to write to the Tally database.
Researching, I discovered it is due to file locking the Tally data is corrupted when multiple clients access it. I did a bind mount of data folder hoping it work initially, but it didn't because of lack of locking support in Linux.
After a bit of digging, I found that there is an option called mand in mount and it can enable mandatory locking that could solve the problem, but the mand mount option was deprecated in the kernel and is removed. Adding it to mount throws an error in dmesg. So mand is out of choice.
I tried to use ntfs-3g hoping its serial IO works like locking, but it failed.
I tried Samba, it works but is very slow that it becomes counter productive solution.
I tried ntfs3, but it lacks locking.
I tried ext4, xfs, ntfs3, ntfs-3g, zfs, FAT all fails.
I wonder how it works so well in Windows when multiple Tally clients access and write data and no issue happens, and this is not at all possible in Linux?
Windows won the game?
I am currently researching if nfsv4 will be a good fit.
In the mean time asking here to see if anyone can help with this issue of sharing data among multiple Tally clients on Linux running on docker?
The goal is to avoid data corruption and make it run stable like in Windows. Any help solving this puzzle is appreciated.

Given how much ongoing pain and cost in time it would be running stuff in Wine through containers sounds like it would be. I'd just pony up the cost of running them on Windows.
I personally wouldn't really trust any software to being production grade quality when it is running through Wine.
Part of the skill of a sysadmin is pragmatism.
Consider the cost in man-hours, licenses and downtime it will be to run this in Wine on containers to the appropriate scale you want.
Now consider the cost in man-hours, licenses and downtime you'd have doing it in Windows.
Choose the most economical.
Not every solution should be nor need be technical.
Sometimes, the pain really isn't worth it, especially for production grade systems.

AWS does it with Wine and its running production grade and stable. AWS’s TallyPrime runs on Wine. I am creating a solution to be sold to customers, so its not a one time work. If I get 1% market share of AWS, thats worth investing into I believe.

AWS has a armies of highly skilled specialized people. You are one guy, with serverfault as your support.

@Sibidharan: does AWS use a flat file that requires range locking as a database? Or are they using ODBC at some point and some clients don't connect to the file? "AWS uses it" is not constructive. If you have a procedure and have questions about it, post it. Don't say "xxx" does it if all that means is I read a blog and someone said it works.

@GregAskew They use flat file that requires range locking for upto 16 users I guess and recommends TallyServer for anything over that count. But still flat file data sharing between multiple containers is available in AWS, they use some custom Arch Linux with Wine.

@Sibidharan: that's a flawed design.

@GregAskew I tried their product hands on, and thats how it designed. The magic is it works, and I also checked they have a custom version of wine running. So I didn't read it in a blog, I experienced it myself. It works there, but they dont recomment it for over 16 people.

@Sibidharan: and they wouldn't even tell you what file system it uses? Red flag.

@GregAskew As far as I searched, its being provided by Tally itself so they are not saying any information on the filesystem backend. I tried to access the terminal but couldn't, they deliberately made it difficult to execute shell commands in that container accessible over browser. Like the terminal binary doesn't exist and from UI every option to run a command is blocked.

NTFS comes with native file-locking support. Not the case with LINUX based systems.
NFSv4 comes with native file locking feauture, but you may experience latency.
If possible, skip TallyPrime & move to a DB.

TallyPrime uses its own embedded database so cant move to a network DB, that is what the client wants and I am willing to setup a opensource solution for them. NFSv4 locking works, but that is not compliing with what Tally Needs.

Try Mounting EFS using NFSv4 on all your Linux containers running TallyPrime.. AWS EFS is optimised for concurrent access by multiple clients or containers, with built-in locking to prevent data corruption.  But, performance and file locking mechanisms needs to be tested carefully to ensure it meets your needs.
